# Here Map Offline turn by turn navigation

Tags: android, here-api

I want to show turn by turn navigation in offline in here map. I have downloaded maps also and setting `MapEngine` as false to use it in offline mode but insufficient map data error is returning while calculating the route. How can I use here map in offline mode?

Comment: INSUFFICIENT_MAP_DATA error code may be returned by CoreRouter because there is not enough local map data to perform route calculation. You can re-download map data and calculate route again. The error may be returned if a route is requested right after MapEngine is initialized but map data request is not completed yet due to network latency.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport can you please provide any offline map implementation example or reference (not maps download part, only offline map access folder) so that I can get some idea about offline implementation. Actually I have changed my code but still getting errors. Maybe I am doing some mistakes in code.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link to know more about the offline map downloading : https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/maps-offline.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with INSUFFICIENT_MAP_DATA. I solved it by setting the device's correct time zone and time.